# Markov chain on a $d$-regular graph

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, convex-optimization, markov-chains

I have a Markov chain on a $d$-regular graph $G(V,E)$. There is a subset of vertices $B$ containing first $b$ vertices. Let $\textbf{b}$ denote an $n \times 1$ vector whose first $b$ entries are $1$ ($b<n$) and remaining are $0$ (last $n-b$ entries are $0$):
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf{b} &= \{1,1,\ldots,1,0,0\ldots,0\}^{T}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The $n \times n$ adjacency matrix, $A$, for $G$ is given as

\begin{equation}
    A(x,y) = 
    \begin{cases}
         1,  & \text{if vertices $x$ and $y$ are neighbours in $G$}\\
         0,  & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

We can define the transition probability matrix, $\mathbf{P}$, for random walk on the graph using $A$.

\begin{equation}
    {\bf P}(x,y) = \frac{A(x,y)}{d}
\end{equation}

Now I begin my random walk $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ from one of the vertices of set B. I want to remain in set B after one step.

\begin{equation}
{\bf P}(X_1 \in B|X_0 \in B) = \frac{{\bf b^TPb}}{b}
\end{equation}

I want to bound this probability: $\hspace{2mm}  \frac{{\bf b^TPb}}{b}$

How can I calculate a bound on this value in terms of $n$, $d$ and $b$?

Comment: $\mathbf{Pb}/b$ is a probability distribution.

Comment: ${\bf b^TPb} \leq b$ seems a pretty loose bound for my analysis. Can I do better?

Comment: Take the $2$-regular graph where vertex 1 and 2 form a connected component and 3 and 4 form another connected component.  Let $b=2$.  Then $\mathbf{b^TPb} = 2 = b$.

Comment: Suppose the graph is strongly connected one.

Comment: Take $b=n$ and you still get $\mathbf{b^TPb} = b$.

Comment: I had mentioned in the problem $b < n$.

Comment: True, but as $n$ grows large...

Comment: Hi Fabio, just check the updated problem. Our discussion just essentially indicates that this probability $\frac{{\bf b^TPb}}{b} \leq 1$. Thats why I wanted a stronger bound.

Comment: I'd say that Misha's answer confirms that you need more than just $n$, $d$, and $b$ to do substantially better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\frac12{\bf b^TAb}$ is just counting the edges in the subgraph induced by $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_b\}$, and ${\bf b^TPb} = {\bf b^TAb}/d$. So in full generality, you can't do better than  $\frac12{\bf b^TAb} \le \binom{b}{2}$ (when $b$ is small) and $\frac12{\bf b^TAb} \le \frac12 bd$ (when $b$ is large) corresponding to $\frac1b {\bf b^TPb} \le \frac{b-1}{d}$, which doesn't do much for us when $b > d$.

Requiring that $G$ is connected is a good first step, but doesn't do much for your bound. It may be that there are very few edges connecting $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_b\}$ to the rest of the graph, in which case you could still end up with a bound like $1 - \frac1{bd}$ or so.

What you *really* want to say is something about the edge expansion of $G$. We can get bounds on this from the eigenvalues of $\bf A$, for instance. If $\lambda_2$ is the second-largest eigenvalue (the largest eigenvalue is trivially $d$) and $b \le \frac n2$, then there are at least $\frac{d-\lambda_2}{2} \cdot b$ edges from $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_b\}$ to $\{v_{b+1}, v_{b+2}, \dots, v_n\}$. So we get a bound of $\frac1b {\bf b^TPb} \le \frac{d + \lambda_2}{2d}$ instead.

(See, e.g., Theorem 4 in [these notes](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/graphtheory-F11/expander1.pdf).)

Comment: After going through the notes, I could not understand the need of the assumption $b \le \frac{n}{2}$. Without the assumption we could have still got this bound -  $\frac1b {\bf b^TPb} \le \frac{b}{n}\frac{d-\lambda_2}{d} + \frac{\lambda_2}{d}$ .

Comment: That seems correct. In most cases, we make that assumption because $e(S,S^c)$ is the quantity we're really interested in, and if $|S| > \frac n2$ we can switch perspectives and get a better bound starting from $S^c$. In your case, you don't want to go to $e(S,S^c)$ so I'm glad I linked you the notes instead of just giving the bound :)